# I'd like to write a condition using Ansible shell feature

Tags: ansible

If Nginx stopped, than print *"Nginx stopped, patching in progress"*.
How to write a condition that Nginx stopped, `Nginx==0` ?

```yaml
---
- hosts: backend
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 
  - name: Patching the back-end servers 
    shell: if nginx == 0 echo "patching has started" fi
```

Comment: `if test ...` If checks the status of a cmd.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use when [`conditional`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) for this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: backend
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 
    - name: Patching the back-end servers 
      shell: echo "patching has started"
      when: nginx == 0
```

If you are also looking for the service status itself, you are then looking for [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html):

```yaml
---
- hosts: backend
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 
    - name: Populate service facts
      service_facts:

    - name: Patching the back-end servers 
      shell: echo "patching has started"
      when: "services_state.ansible_facts.services['ngnix'].state == 'stopped'"
```

Comment: fatal: [backend]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'nginx == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (nginx == 0): 'nginx' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook.yml': line 8, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Check if nginx running\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: @Manny since you where using it like that in your example, I wrongly assumed that the variable was set somewhere in your play. Use the second part of the answer, then as it also check the service status.